# Nodejs https .post() request; is there a faster way than via the request package?

Tags: api, http-post, distributed-transactions, algorithmic-trading, poloniex

So, I have been reading about automated (crypto) trading and I thought lets give it a shot. I've been able to make a simple trader for the Poloniex exchange.

My idea is to make multiple trades in succession, such that when the first trade is done it gives a signal to start the second trade and so on.

The buy/sell trades are sent, via the `HTTPS POST` method, to the Poloniex API.

I want the timespan of several successive trades to be minimal. However, I noticed that **a single buy/sell request takes approximately `500 [ms]`** (sometimes even more than a sec) with the npm request package.

Now I wonder if there is a faster method to send these `HTTPS POST` requests, such that the chance of the price being changed at the second successive request is minimal.

My current method is as follows:

```
            //   create timestamp and encrypt secret
            //                              + message
            //   with current timestamp using Hmac
            timeStamp = Math.floor(Date.now());
            sign = ...

            var headers = {
                'Key':    key,
                'Sign':   sign
            };

            // make first trade
            request.post({
                'headers': headers,
                'url':    'https://poloniex.com/tradingApi',
                'form':    ... 
            }, function (error, response, body) {
                // go on to second trade if previous finished correctly
                if (!error)
                {
                    // use same procedure again for encryption
                    timeStamp = Math.floor(Date.now());
                    sign      = ... 

                    headers = {
                        'Key':    key,
                        'Sign':   sign
                    };

                    request.post({
                        'headers': headers,
                        'url':    'https://poloniex.com/tradingApi',
                        'form':    ...
                    }, function (error, response, body) {
                        if (!error)
                        {
                         // same pattern for the third one
```

Answer (score 0):

**A proposal to buy a slightly better computer** (ref. below ) for accelerated SSL-encryption/decryptions phase ( step [3] below ), with an additional remark, that most of the 500 [ms] is probably mostly **just the response time for the server** you're sending to." **is** ( with all due respect ) **straight wrong and heavily misleading statement**.

*( cit., emphases added )* :

> <sub>"... It's possible that **a slightly faster computer** might do the SSL connection calculations faster for the initial connection, but that's just a guess. FYI, you don't have to wait for one transaction to finish before starting the next one. You can start multiple transactions at once an see when they are all done. They will all then be "in flight" at the same time. **The 500ms delay you notice is probably mostly just the response time for the server you're sending to.** – jfriend00 10 hours ago "</sub>

<sub>( ***Ooops***, this comment that I still see here, on the screen, signed by [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00), dated `[2017-10-27 09:15:37Z]` ... now seems to get deleted by author, instead of being explicit to address the below requested clarification of how many [ms] would indeed get shaved-off, as she/he proposed to use a slightly faster computer to the O/P )</sub>

---

### Well, this is a typical result of choosing straight WRONG tools ...

> [image]
>   Carefully read the actual **`e2e.RTT`** figures,
> and also their **variance** ( that are two orders of magnitude larger, than a common latency-noise on an L3-network delivery phase ),
> which
>  only if observed together reflect indeed the real-world End-To-End Round-Trip-Time of a confirmation for the simplest of all the XTO-instructions, that does not require any additional [Risk-Management] or other post-processing on the API-provider BackOffice/NDD/ECN-side
> Also one can see
> how many missing answers from the API-provider were lost -- sent **`BEEP[7238]`** vs received just **`LAST[7206]`**
> **Got ready to process even lost API-calls?**

Having been in FX-markets technology domain more than a few decades ( few > 3 ), I feel I can tell these points:

- Market-Access Provider ( you name them all ) decided to sell/provide API to public
- Their CIO + COO have decided to wrap + lightweight-encrypt services into **`HTTPS`**-envelopes
- Your Application simply has to meet their logic of the API-Finite-State-Machine, incl. their chosen re-wrapping everything into/out from `HTTPS`-envelopes.

---

## How it works:

1. Your app-logic may get decided, **[NOW]**, to send some
   XTO-instruction to the Trading Engine
2. At this moment, your app has to perform XTO-instruction re-formulation into the format, the remotely operated API can both receive and process. This takes some time, typically not more than **a few tens of  ~ [us]**
3. Next, your API-conformant XTO-instruction has to be wrapped + encrypted into the `HTTPS`-envelope, again **a few tens of ~ [us] added**
4. Next, your localhost marshalls the `HTTPS`-envelope to your LAN interface, **add a few [us]**
5. Your next hurdle is to deliver such envelope over public internet ( be it the global one ( paying **+1 .. +10 [ms]** over the Continent, **or ~ +100 [ms]** if connected over submarine cables or via satcom from New Zealand et al ), **OR** in case the named Provider's-local intranet has exposed in their colocated datacentre a zone for colocated peering ( there paying the costs of just a few feet ( **+ a ~ few [ns]** ) over a 10GBE cable ( if the API Provider have such offer for you ) ).
6. Here -- still not the end of the story -- your `HTTPS`-wrapped envelope has just reached the input-port of the **queue** of Provider's own API-providing-Gateway, so none processing has started up to this point, until which you have already collected a lot of hundreds of [us] ( at least ). The said API provider will at some time later pop-your `HTTPS`-envelope from the queue so as to start decoding + unwrapping the content of the queue-released `HTTPS`-envelope ( **add a cost of a +few [us]**, depending on traffic patterns and queueing policies operated at the API-providing-Gateway + decoding depends on what technology they use for this decomposition, even the most sophisticated silicon-based technology cannot perform this any much faster )
7. After previous step, the API-providing-Gateway can deliver your decoded XTO-instruction into the API-service ( guess what, **add a few +[us]** for this step )
8. API-FSA here starts to translate your API-conformant XTO-instruction into the Trade Execution ( depending on spare performance and workload/traffic-patterns, **here you pay a few tens, hundreds, thousands [ms]** depending also on how smart integrated tools the Trade Execution venue has and how tricky their risk-assessment, price-feeds, liquidity-pool and archipelago-book maintenance that NDD/ECN execution engines and policies work with and which finally set the there-actual MarketPrice(s) the XTO will be executed at.

> **--------** up to here, it was a **time-**(price)**-critical** part of a single XTO-transaction end-to-end path.

9. Once your XTO was actually "matched" on the order-book records, the confirmations will get created, so as to be sent back to your side ( time-non-critical operation, so do not expect any top-priorities, neither in processing, nor in queueing policies to take place, so **add +few [ms]** )
10. For the sake of delivery, repeat the same sequence of steps -- API-conformant answer assembly + queuing + API-response translation in an API-providing-Gateway onto text-format with HTTPS-encryption + queueing + series of all involved ISO/OSI-L3 delivery routes ( be it colocated or over a global network )
11. Here, your LAN has delivered a series of IP-packets to your localhost interface to unpack, decrypt, transform and start to decode the meaning of the message.
12. At this moment, your XTO-instruction's response could be compared and best matched with the intent of the XTO-instruction originally sent.
13. **Press the Stopwatch** to read the **`E2E-RTT`** duration.

> This is **why** you can meet something from a few tens of [us] to **anything above +1000 [ms]**

---

### How do it The Bests of The Bests?

- **avoid** Projects to start without a thorough validation of their feasibility ( both in the sense of latency-envelopes under high workloads and overall scaling ) -- things that may work under easy workloads tend to show nasty surprises and extraordinary troubles under heavy and long-lasting load-patterns and spurious storms ...
- **avoid** relying on "Wannabe-TechGuru(s)" ( even if all speak about REST/HTTP-based API, never move this sort of experience outside of the zone, where it may suffice, the less into the zone, where ultimately tight real-time control-loops cannot deliver stable results )
- **avoid** following "Marketing" quasi-arguments ( even if all speak about some  technology -- be it { JSON | XML | CORBA-BLOBs } -- never take such technology automatically for your latency-sensistive real-time distributed system, et al )
- **introduce** low-latency tools + avoiding any expensive overheads
- **never** re-wrap things ( best delivered in binary-dense maps )
- **always** profile timestamp timings and log / reconcile records of evidence against contracted Terms & Conditions, requesting financial remedies if T&C not met or otherwise violated in production ( this is a long story to go )

---

### The best next step?

If you have reached reading down to this trailer, you must have noticed, none of these choices above were actually your one.

You will under all circumstance bear the risk of price-shifts between item **`[1..8]`** and subject to price-slippage inside **`[8]`**

Best go and ask for a better and faster API + a co-located server-hosting.

---

### BONUS:

If indeed in a search for an advanced

> "method to send  ... requests, such that the chance of the price being changed at the second successive request is minimal."

then listen -- there is a way -- in case your trading-strategy does **not** require to interact with the E2E-distributed-transaction confirmations / **`{ price | DoM-L3 }`**-changes, announced asynchronously via all incoming `[_>>_price-stream_>>_]`-channel(s), simply go smart and submit all such XTO-instructions in **`[PARALLEL]`** at once ( there are proven ways to do it on your local-side ).

Using this approach, your salvo will simply sip-out all necessary liquidity from the actual state of the Order-Book at the best-execution price ( if not tricked by the operator policies ( again, see the journalling records-of-evidence to check and potentially ask FSA to protect your interests in case any fair trading + fair price discreapancies were present ) ).

### Update

OK, @jfriend00 stepped in and objected *( cit., emphases added )*:

> <sub>You way **over complicated** the question asked. The OP has an HTTP API and they want to know if they can do anything faster than the request() module to make requests to that API. That's the question asked. You don't address that at all and you go into all sorts of stuff that has absolutely nothing to do with the question asked. A **long**, **complicated**, **hard to understand** answer that **doesn't actually even answer the question** that was asked is what downvotes are for. – jfriend00 28 mins ago</sub>

to be:

- ***long***  -- well, sure -- the algorithmic-trading infrastructures are **NOT** SIMPLEX
- ***complicated***  --  the multi-party ( opposite interests ) distributed-transactions **ARE** COMPLICATED
- ***hard to understand*** -- anyone may show up here and explain such complex E2E problem better
- ***not addressing the question*** -- the only meaningful solution **WAS** provided, **together with** all relevant **arguments, WHY any other** ( simpler, isolated on just one step, or even over-simplified to become "easier" ) **WILL NOT WORK** for the problem the O/P is facing.

Sorry to have to repeat that, after 30+ years I dare tell you I pretty well know there is none other <sub>( and if still in doubts, re-think the story -- ***if there were any***, all the top-ranking HFT-sharks would already have demonstrated their immediate move into it. So, if none of them has gone into any such easy & trivial magic shot, but all remain right in the perimeter of the below explained best known solution, that is a clear and sound evidence, none better exists. **Q.E.D.** )</sub>

Comment: I don't see where you actually answered the OP's question and your answer seems to contain a lot of stuff that is both hard to understand and not particular relevant to the question actually asked.  The OP does not indicate they have any control at all over the back-end.  They are given an HTTP API and are asking how they can best use that.  I don't see anywhere in all your rambling where you address the question that is asked.

Comment: Aha, O/P problem -- "How to speed-up a distributed-transaction processing" -- was explained in terms of what has to happen before he/she gets End-to-End delivered confirmation of any XTO-instruction. I could understand, that non-FinTech users, who have never implemented a distributed-transaction near-real-time system, may feel hard to understand each and every step, but it was not an authors fault that the multi-party distributed-transaction system is so complex ( **as it indeed is**, no doubt about that ). Still, a faster SSH-cryptor for just a step [3] cannot and will not help lower the RTT.

Comment: No.  You way over complicated the question asked.  The OP has an HTTP API and they want to know if they can do anything faster than the `request()` module to make requests to that API.  That's the question asked.  You don't address that at all and you go into all sorts of stuff that has absolutely nothing to do with the question asked.  A long, complicated, hard to understand answer that doesn't actually even answer the question that was asked is what downvotes are for.

Comment: @jfriend00 After explaining both the (time)-critical-part ( that directly affects the losses from shifted XTO-instruction execution-price ) and the (non-prioritised)-RTB-part, where just an XTO-confirmation/-rejection/-dropped information flows back, **the answer WAS** delivered "**Best go and ask for a better and faster API + a co-located server-hosting.**" ( *because any other step would not help O/P a bit on the main goal* **such that the chance of the price being changed at the second successive request is minimal.** )

Comment: @jfriend00 After 30+ years in the FinTech ultra-low-latency trading, one may believe the distributed-infrastructure could hardly be more / better simplified. ( without missing any principal component, adding some remarkable part to the RTT delays ). If you still argue that a new FERRARI in step [3] will also solve all the other principal delays, incl. uncertain ranges of processing delays introduced in Broker [Risk Management] + [Market Matching] engines behind the remote API-providing-Gateway, it would deliver false promises to O/P, as this will not help but a step [3]. Going co-located will.

Comment: So you object that the answer is *( cit. )* **long**. Yes, it is. It must be, if one wants to know why -- it is a complex multi-party distributed-transaction confirmation system ( and it trades in real-time in as fast as money-markets do pace ... ). No shorter way IMHO ( having 30+ years hands on experiend ) exists ( dogmatic "truths" a lá "Deus Ex Machina" are excluded due to having zero chance of cross-validation against real-world system behaviour ). **Let's test your proposal. How many [ms] will your advice shave-off once using a faster computer for the step [3], as you proposed above?**

Comment: Hey user3666197 and jfriend00, I see you guys are getting along well. Nonetheless, I really appreciate both your answers. I like the detailed explanation of user3666197 as it gives me some idea of how it works, although it is quite complex.

Comment: So, I think I can say that, for me as a client, it is simply not possible to reduce my ms since I want to do some form of arbitrage which does not allow me to start multiple transactions at once (at least I think).

Comment: I am glad you appreciate the pieces of knowledge sponsored in the answer. Some Community member seem to hate this scope of insight. Feel free to express your already reflected appreciation by voting +1, I would be personally grateful to anyone, who would give me a similar vertical End-to-End explanation of the [algoritmic-trading] infrastructure mechanics in less than a few years ( and for free **:o)** ... )

Comment: It looks like both of you know a lot about algorithmic trading. Which actually brings me to another question: Is it even possible for me to perform high-frequency arbitrage trading on a crypto exchange?

Comment: Well, you can start multiple transactions at one ( ref. Bonus part above ), the problem is with rolling-forward distributed-transactions' duration and uncertain remote-acknowledgement of an XTO-instruction. **Saying you are willing go into arbitrage-trading, the co-location is a must, if serious about this idea.** One can have any amount of D-Wave Quantum computers to be faster in arbitrage-chain finding, the XTO-instruction actual execution decides, if one gets out of an arbitrage-chain in black, or straight bankrupt (a long story). **Yet, co-location may get you into doing this business**

Comment: Where did you find any [algorithmic-trading] answer from the "angry person" who has inquisitively protested that the complex systems were described End-to-End so as to become possible to explain the answer altogether with a due reasoning as complex systems, because it is a complex system? I have found none so far >>> https://stackoverflow.com/tags/algorithmic-trading/topusers

Comment: Some people explain things more complex, some less. He actually gave me a quick and summarized answer for someone of my level. You're right, I thought I saw a comment from him regarding trading, but I must have misread it. 

In the bonus you say that sending multiple XTO-instructions might do the trick. This is not equal to sending parallel post requests I suppose?

And regarding the co-location, I don't think I am in a position to acquire something like that.

Comment: Our system went to a similar need to do a bit of similar thing ( yet not for an arbitrage case ), where E2E latency-masking helped a lot and we indeed have fired a rather impressive salvo of XTO-instructions, right due to a need to escape from an otherwise unavoidable [SERIAL]-ordering one-duck-after-another. It worked as hell. As for the co-location -- ask the Business Rep. of your API-provider, they may surprise you with a feasible offer. It is a common practice to get fair offers with less than 1 [ms] L3-distance ( in time :o) ) from a serious Trading Venue professional. So rather go for it

Comment: Sorry user3666197, me again. We alternate between accepting each other's viewpoint, and not, so I flip a coin and hope that some of the following advice is acceptable to you. It is hard to overstate how confusing this answer is, and the formatting really doesn't help. Addenda seem to have been added at the start of the post with each successive edit, and meta/voting commentary is being added despite your having been suspended for that previously. Quote blocks are added that are not actually quotes (the "wrong tools" section), prompting the reader to wonder which voice to read each section in.

Comment: It seems that the post still begins with a response to a comment, and that section could do with excising, in my opinion, since this turns your answer into a discussion (not what _Stack Overflow_ is for). Your two lists are probably the bulk of the answer, and perhaps could be presented on their own.

Comment: I have no view on jfriend00, and it isn't really up to community members to arbitrate arguments here - that's a case for diamond mods. I'm an editor, so I concentrate on editing. (jfriend00 did make an answer, but since that's deleted, there is no value in editing it). FWIW, my advice is not to worry about the odd downvote - that's 1 point of reputation, and it can be ignored. You post frequently enough that you'll make up the loss in less than a day.

Comment: @user3666197: if you're referring to deleted comments, only mods can see those. I agree that high-rep users should be exemplars of good behaviour, and I agree not all meet those standards. I can't comment on this case. If you believe that a user has been abusive, mod flag their comment, or if they self-deleted, mod-flag the post and explain the problem. In general abusive comments are merely deleted, as mods tend to prefer a "light touch", but sometimes it can be helpful for mods to have reports to hand, in case a user produces more flaggable behaviour in the future.

Comment: You may be out of options. If the problem is "unjustified" downvotes, there is a firm site consensus that _people may vote anonymously for any reason they like, as long as they don't vote by user_. Additionally, given that we also don't want meta-commentary injected into questions or answers (I remove it frequently from new users' questions), it really is best to ignore it. However if you have a solid proposal to improve site operation in this context, you can always write a suggestion on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: (You could also lobby on Meta for more lee-way to add voting commentary and complaints to posts themselves, but I am 99% sure that idea will be heavily downvoted and chased away in short order. Nevertheless you are welcome to try! I would personally disagree with such a proposal, since I think it conflicts with the aims of the site, which is to produce clean and clear Q&A without any distracting politics for readers to skip over).